# Derivatives of mollified functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm reading *Controlled Diffusion Process* by N.V. Krylov. On page 87-88, in the proof of theorem II.6.1, it says the following:
Let $\sigma(t,x)$ be a matrix of dimension $d\times d$, and let $b(t,x)$ be a $d$-dimensional vector. Assume that $\sigma(t,x)$, $b(t,x)$ are given for $t\geq 0$, $x \in E_d$ ($d$-dimensional Euclidean space), also, in addition, are bounded and Borel-measurable with respect to $(t,x)$. Also, let the matrix $\sigma(t,x)$ be positive definite, and moreover let $(\sigma(t,x)\lambda,\lambda)\geq\delta |\lambda|^2$ for some constant $\delta >0$ for all $(t,x), \lambda \in E^d$. Let $\sigma^n(t,x)= \sigma_{\epsilon_n}(t,x)$, $b^n(t,x)=b_{\epsilon_n}(t,x)$ be the mollifications of $\sigma$, $b$, where $\epsilon_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\epsilon \neq 0$. Clearly $\sigma_n \rightarrow \sigma$, $b_n \rightarrow b$ almost surely as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Then it says on the 6th line of page 88:
Note that the derivatives of $\sigma_n$, $b_n$ are bounded for each $n$. Hence the functions $\sigma_n$, $b_n$ satisfy the Lipschitz condition.

I don't understand why the mollified functions have bounded derivatives. Please help.

Thanks!

Edit: Do we consider $C^\infty$ as a Fréchet space with the norm $\sup_{n,x}|f^{(n)}(x)|$ in this context (hence $f\in C^\infty$ has finite derivatives)? Either way, if anyone could clarify or give an outline of a proof that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $B$ is a bounded function, and $\eta_{\epsilon}$ is a mollifier, then $\eta_{\epsilon}$ is in $C^{\infty}_{c}$. So every derivative of $\eta_{\epsilon}$ is absolutely integrable. Therefore $\int B(y)\eta_{\epsilon}(x-y)dy$ is uniformly bounded if $B$ is bounded by $M$. And $|\int B(y)D\eta_{\epsilon}(x-y)dy| \le M\int |D\eta_{\epsilon}(x-y)dy| \le MK$ for any derivative operator $D$ with constant coefficients of any order. The bound $K$ changes as $\epsilon\downarrow 0$, but that's not relevant in what you're trying to do.

Comment: I already figured it out but still thanks a lot! :)